# How to use raw_input() with while-loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

my task is to execute multiple buffers with the list-loop!

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\salzburg.gdb"  
sbgRivers="sbg_rivers"
buff_name=raw_input("Please insert a file name:")  
for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:  
    outfile="C:\\salzburg.gdb\\buffer_output"
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgRivers,buff_name+str(buffer_size),buffer_size)  
    print "Buffer complete"
```

So the next step is: If the file name already exists(raw_input), the user is asked to enter a new data set name until a name is found, which doesn´t exist yet!

I thought about a while loop, but i´m not sure how to integrate it in the code above

i ended up with this

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\salzburg.gdb"  
sbgRivers="sbg_rivers"
buff_name=raw_input("Please insert a new data set name:")
while arcpy.Exists(buff_name):    
    buff_name=raw_input("Please enter a new data set name")  
    for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:    
         arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgRivers,buff_name+str(buffer_size),buffer_size) 
         print "Buffer complete"
```

What do you think? Any help is welcome and appreciated!

Comment: If it works and it is (relatively) concise, I guess it's fine. Otherwise, you should check it out on codereview

Comment: I don't see a problem with it! But in future make sure your indentation is expressed in your formatting. I also second it should really be on code review

Comment: It looks like the `for` loop should be put outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to first make sure that you have the correct filename and then proceed to the next step. The code should be: (assuming `arcpy.Exists(buff_name)` does what it is supposed to do, because I think it should be `arcpy.Exists(buff_name+str(100))` or something like it.)

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  
arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\salzburg.gdb"  
sbgRivers="sbg_rivers"
buff_name=raw_input("Please insert a new data set name:")
while arcpy.Exists(buff_name):    
    buff_name=raw_input("Name already exists. Please enter a new data set name")  
for buffer_size in [100,200,300,450]:    
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sbgRivers,buff_name+str(buffer_size),buffer_size) 
    print "Buffer complete"
```

Your previous code would have run the for loop for all the inputs provided (even the wrong ones).

Answer (score 0):

Ok If you Want to use input() In a while loop the  code will be like this:

```
sett=True
while sett:
    buff_name=raw_input("Please insert a file name:")  
    if buff_name=="":
        continue 
    else: 
        break ##Or: sett=False
```